Who are the characters in the House of the Dragon S02E06 intro tapestry featuring three dragons and a Targaryen wielding a sword?
In the opening credits of House of the Dragon Season 2, we're treated to a series of tapestries that illustrate various events from House Targaryen's history. One tapestry in particular, featured in episode 6's intro, depicts what appears to be a Targaryen figure standing in a valley, gripping a sword with both hands and holding it high.
It's unclear whether the figure is about to execute someone lying on the ground or if they're simply brandishing the sword in a powerful pose. There are also two dragons near the Targaryen and another dragon soaring in the sky.

I'm curious if this tapestry might be referencing a specific event from the A Song of Ice and Fire universe. If so, can anyone identify the event, the person wielding the sword, and the identities of the three dragons? I thought the figure might be Aegon I, but his dragon, Balerion (known for its black coloring), doesn't seem to be present.

I have not watched the series.... But to me It's hard to recognize a person at his feet. (Looks like he is standing on a pile of rocks?) He also appears to also be looking to our right in the tapestry, and NOT looking down or ahead as if to be about to hack someone lying on the ground at his feet.

@NJohnny Interesting take! I hadn't considered that angle. I'll take another look and update my question to include this perspective.

I believe this is supposed to be a depiction of the Battle of Rook's Rest.
The chief evidence of this is that so far the tapestry has changed only to depict new events in the series. When the season started, the opening credits featured the death of Lucerys.

Partway through the season, that was changed to depict the death of the infant Prince Jaehaerys and the hanging of the ratcatchers.

So the smart money is that this is supposed to depict the most recent "big event" in the series. The two dragons on the ground would be Meleys and Sunfyre, who were killed and badly wounded respectively, and the dragon flying away would be Vhaegar.
The burned body is certainly Aegon, which means the figure with the sword is supposed to be Aemond (who, as you may recall, stood over his body with his sword unsheathed).

I see. Initially, I didn't think this scene was related to that event, but I can see how it fits now.
